# Reverse lookup of dtype

Tags: numpy

I want to find dtype of `int` whose itemsize is k.

Expected Behavior

```
 >>> print(lookup(2))
 <class 'numpy.int16'>

 >>> print(lookup(4))
 <class 'numpy.int32'>

 >>> print(lookup(8))
 <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

where `lookup` is the function I want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.sctypes`:

```
lookup = {t().itemsize: t for t in np.sctypes['int']}

lookup
# {1: <class 'numpy.int8'>, 2: <class 'numpy.int16'>, 4: <class 'numpy.int32'>, 8: <class 'numpy.int64'>}
```

Or use `np.sctypeDict` and f-strings:

```
def lookup(n):
    return np.sctypeDict[f'i{n}']

[lookup(n) for n in (1, 2, 4, 8)]
# [<class 'numpy.int8'>, <class 'numpy.int16'>, <class 'numpy.int32'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>]
```